# Creating Private API

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a very simple api gateway in aws. This api doesn't need any authentication.

The problem is I have depoloyed the app in ec2 instance and when I access the application's api with IP on the browser, it returns the output in JSON format.

For. Eg.

on Chrome/Curl - http:/10.x.x.x:9090/service/test

But when I do http integration in API gateway with same url as endpoint, and hit test it gives me "500 internal server error". I have already tried the following -

1. Create an API as private one.
2. Enable resource policy with VPC endpoint
3. There is no authentication required to access API(I am able to see it in chrome)

But still I get the problem. Any insight or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to see the detailed log when you run the `test` in API Gateway. What does it say? I guess the necessary parameters or headers might not be given correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`500 Internal Server` errors should be checked in the execution CloudWatch logs of the API. These errors indicate -

1. The API either failed to hit the integration (Lambda, HTTP etc.) or
2. The integration request returned an unsuccessful response.
3. The response received by the integration was not supported by the API (in case of proxy integrations)

Some examples of 5XX errors that can be seen in the logs which generate `500 Internal Server` on the client-side:

1. `502 Malformed Proxy` - With a proxy integration, the response sent from the backend was not in the [expected format](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/).
2. `504 Endpoint timed-out` - The API failed to receive a response back in 29 seconds from the integration.
3. `502 Bad Gateway` -  usually for an incompatible output returned from a Lambda proxy integration backend and occasionally for out-of-order invocations due to heavy loads.

To enable CloudWatch executions logs, follow the steps [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/).

Read more about handling 5XX errors in API Gateway [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/handling-errors/).